# Unable to install VMware Player: Module VPMC power on failed

Tags: vmware-player

I want to install Ubuntu on my VMware Player, but I facing the following error:

```
Virtualized performance counters are not supported on the host CPU type.
Module VPMC power on failed. Failed to start the virtual machine`
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I also had problems with VMware but VirtualBox works like a charm. Have you tried it?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Edit the `.vmx` file and search for `vpmc.enabled`. Set it to `FALSE`.

More about performance counters here:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2030221

Comment: Nice solution, this was help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Virtualized performance counters are not supported on the host CPU type

This error report clearly shows that your host CPU model won't support Virtualization. So you can't run any Virtualization softwares like VirtualBox,VMWare,etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can I use VMWare player? maybe can I use another version of VM?

Comment: try [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). If the problem still persists, then you have to do with with host machine.

Comment: Could also try with Qemu, which support both CPU-based VM emulation (which the host processor does not support) and fully software virtualization (which is much slower).

Comment: This answer is not correct. The host CPU may support virtualization except that you will not be able to access the performance counters of the host CPU. The virtualized OS cannot also virtualize performance counters. In VMware for instance, you have to disable all sorts of virtualization and disable access to performance counters (under Processors). To be entirely sure, in the .vmx file, search for *vpmc* and if found, set the value to False.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on my Mac after upgrading to a new Macbook pro. I went to the VM settings, then Processor and Memory tab, then "advanced options" and uncheck both options. I was then able to boot up the virtual machine.

Comment: Update: For me it is sufficient to only disable code profiling which uses performance counters of the CPU.